# AVRCP key events handled in linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, kernel, bluez, avrcp

AVRCP key events are handled in bluez within avdtp file which invokes uinput module in kernel. Can anyone suggest me how these key events are send to application to play/pause/rewind , is any key listener present which sends these key events to respective applications or if applications listen to key events, do they need to subscribe to some service?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

depending on which blueZ version you are using, you can do following,
take a look at the test of blues for single-endpoint. there is implemented a Control interface, and if you use some tool like Dfeet, then you can see the interfaces related to it, so that you can call  stop, play, next commands...